# CRSF TOKEN with PHP CURL does not work

Tags: php

I am developing php curl with automatic login to website. However, I am in problem that this site need send _csrf_token to server.
My code is below. First, the program is called addLoginData($users), then, getToken() and getHTTPContent().

I do not know why code does not work.

```
public function addLoginData($users)
{
    foreach($users as $user)
    {

        $login_arr = array(
            /*'commit' => 'Login',
            'nickname' => $user['username'],
            'password' => $user['password'],
            'save_cookie' => '1'*/
            '_csrf_token' => $this->getToken(),
            'action'     => 'login',
            'commit' => 'Einloggen',
            'invisibility' => 0,
            'nickname' =>   $user['username'],
            'online_status' => 0,
            'password' =>   $user['password'],
            'referer' => '@homepage_guest',
            'remember_me' => 1
        );          
        array_push($this->loginArr, $login_arr);
    }
}
public function getToken()
{   
    $content = $this->getHTTPContent($this->loginURL,$this->rootDomain);        
    $token = '';
    if(!empty($content)) {          
        $html = str_get_html($content);
        if($html->find("input[name=_csrf_token]",0)) {
            foreach($html->find("input[name=_csrf_token]") as $span) {          
                $token = $span->value;  
            }
        }
    }       
    return $token;
}
protected function getHTTPContent($url, $referer, $cookiePath=null, $postContent=null, $get_info = FALSE, $header = null)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    if($this->command['proxy_type'] != 3 && !empty($this->proxy_ip) && !empty($this->proxy_port) && !empty($this->proxy_type)){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy_ip);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $this->proxy_port);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, $this->proxy_type);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOP  T_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem");
    $this->savelog("=>".$ch);   
    print_r($ch);
    if($header !== null) {
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    }


    if($cookiePath !== null)
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiePath);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiePath);
    }

    if($postContent !== null || $this->nullPost == 1)
    {   

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        if($this->nullPost == 0) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, (($this->_special_post == 1) ? $postContent : http_build_query($postContent)));
            $this->_special_post = 0;
            if($this->_special_post == 1){
                echo 'Special Search';
            }
            var_dump($postContent);
        }
        $this->nullPost = 0;
    }

    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $header  = curl_getinfo($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    echo '<p>URL : ', $url,'</p>';
    echo '<p><textarea style="width:600px; height:400px;">',$content,'</textarea></p>';

    if(empty($content)) {
        $this->savelog('No Response from url : '.$url.' / Proxy : '.$this->proxy_ip.':'.$this->proxy_port); botutil::setNoResponse($this->commandID, TRUE, $this);
    } else {
        botutil::setNoResponse($this->commandID, FALSE, $this);
    }

    if($get_info === TRUE) {
        return array(
            'header' => $header,
            'content' => $content
        );
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: What on Earth do you mean by *it doesn't work*? Any errors? Blank page? Any logs errors? Please be specific.

Comment: how do you call these methods? could you please show the main code?

Comment: It means the website return authentication login page to me when I pass those parameters  '_csrf_token' => $this->getToken(),
            'action'     => 'login',
            'commit' => 'Einloggen',
            'invisibility' => 0,
            'nickname' =>   $user['username'],
            'online_status' => 0,
            'password' =>   $user['password'],
            'referer' => '@homepage_guest',
            'remember_me' => 1

Comment: I call this function login()

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Tufan Barış Yıldırım, the login function is below.   
 public function login()
{
    $this->userAgent = botutil::getAgentString();       
    $this->currentUser = 0;
    $username = $this->loginArr[$this->currentUser][$this->usernameField];
    $cookiePath = $this->getCookiePath($username);
    $this->user_name = $username;

    if(!($this->isLoggedIn($username)))
    {
        $this->savelog("This profile: ".$username." does not log in.");
        // count try to login
        for($count_login=1; $count_login<=$this->loginRetry; $count_login++)
        {
            if($this->command["proxy_type"] == 1){

                if($this->tor_new_identity($this->proxy_ip,$this->proxy_control_port,'bot')){
                    $this->savelog("New Tor Identity request completed.");
                }else{
                    $this->savelog("New Tor Identity request failed.");
                }

            }

            $this->savelog("Logging in.");

            // Log
            $content = $this->getHTTPContent($this->loginActionURL, $this->rootDomain, $cookiePath, $this->loginArr[$this->currentUser]);
            if(!empty($content)) {
                file_put_contents("login/".$username."-".date("YmdHis").".html",$content);
            }


            if(empty($content))
            {

                $this->savelog("No response from server.");
                $this->loginRetry++;
            }
            else if(!($this->isLoggedIn($username)))
            {

                $this->savelog("Log in failed with profile: ".$username);
                $this->savelog("Log in failed $count_login times.");

                if($count_login>($this->loginRetry-1))
                {
                    $this->savelog("User ".$username." tried to login ".$count_login." times. This username would be deleted.");
                    DBConnect::execute_q("UPDATE user_profiles SET status='false' WHERE site_id=".$this->siteID." AND username='".$this->loginArr[$this->currentUser]['data']['User'][$this->usernameField]."'");
                    $this->command['profile_banned'] = TRUE;
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $sleep_time = 120; // 2 mins
                    $this->_session_id = NULL;
                    $this->savelog("Sleep after log in failed for ". $this->secondToTextTime($sleep_time));
                    $this->sleep($sleep_time);
                }
            } else {
                botutil::profileCount($this->getSiteID(), $username);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    $username = $this->loginArr[$this->currentUser][$this->usernameField];
    $cookiePath = $this->getCookiePath($username);
    $this->savelog("Logging out.");
    $content = $this->getHTTPContent($this->logoutURL. time(), $this->rootDomain, $cookiePath);
    return true;
}
```